# Information is not saved in mysql database after submitting in form

Tags: php, html

This is the code for saving the information into **mysql** database from a FORM.
In the **HTML** section the form is being handled i.e. retrieving required data from user.
In the **PHP** section storing data has been handled.
But the problem is it doesn't store data.
I'm using **XAMPP** server.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>signup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/insert.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="maindiv">
    <!--HTML form -->
        <div class="form_div">
            <div class="title"><h2>Insert Data In Database Using PHP.</h2>      </div>

            <form action="signup.php" method="post">    <!-- method can be set POST for hiding values in URL-->
                <h2>Form</h2>

                <label>Name:</label>
                <br />
                <input class="input" type="text" name="name" value=""  />
                <br />
                <label>Email:</label><br />        
                <input class="input" type="text" name="mail"  value=""  />
                <br />

                <label>Phone:</label><br />        
                <input class="input" type="text" name="phone"  value=""  />
                <br />
                <label>Password:</label><br />        
                <input class="input" type="text" name="pass"  value=""  />
                <br />

                <label>Address:</label><br />
                <textarea rows="5" cols="25" name="add"></textarea>
                <br />

                <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit"    value="Insert" />  

<?php
//Establishing Connection with Server
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "buet2010");

//Selecting Database from Server
$db = mysql_select_db("tanni", $connection);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL

$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$add = $_POST['add'];
if($name !=''||$email !=''){
//Insert Query of SQL
$query = mysql_query($db, "INSERT INTO user (name, mail, phone, pass, add)VALUES('$name', '$mail', '$phone', '$pass', '$add')");
echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
}
else{
echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";   
}

}
//Closing Connection with Server
mysql_close($connection);
?>                  
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

I don't understand what can be the problem.

Thanks all. I got the problem.
Actually the sequence of the column in my database was not matching with the query in php code.

Comment: What is $query. If it is FALSE the query did not go well .. .. so make a if($query) to test

Comment: My Problem is SOLVED! thanks all !!

Comment: Please make sure to post your own answer for others to use in the future

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this by changing the variable sequence in the query which is maintained in the database.

```
 $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (`name`, `mail`, `pass`, `address`, `phone`)VALUES('".$name."', '".$mail."', '".$pass."', '".$address."', '".$phone."')");
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code and it will work for your..
I have passed connection link in your mysql_query. and used PHP_SELF for current page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>signup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/insert.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="maindiv">
    <!--HTML form -->
        <div class="form_div">
            <div class="title"><h2>Insert Data In Database Using PHP.</h2>      </div>

            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">    <!-- method can be set POST for hiding values in URL-->
                <h2>Form</h2>

                <label>Name:</label>
                <br />
                <input class="input" type="text" name="name" value=""  />
                <br />
                <label>Email:</label><br />        
                <input class="input" type="text" name="mail"  value=""  />
                <br />

                <label>Phone:</label><br />        
                <input class="input" type="text" name="phone"  value=""  />
                <br />
                <label>Password:</label><br />        
                <input class="input" type="text" name="pass"  value=""  />
                <br />

                <label>Address:</label><br />
                <textarea rows="5" cols="25" name="add"></textarea>
                <br />

                <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit"    value="Insert" />  

<?php
//Establishing Connection with Server
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "buet2010");

//Selecting Database from Server
$db = mysql_select_db("tanni", $connection);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL

$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$add = $_POST['add'];
if($name !=''||$email !=''){
//Insert Query of SQL
$query = mysql_query($db, "INSERT INTO user (name, mail, phone, pass, add)VALUES('$name', '$mail', '$phone', '$pass', '$add')",$connection);
echo "<br/><br/><span>Data Inserted successfully...!!</span>";
}
else{
echo "<p>Insertion Failed <br/> Some Fields are Blank....!!</p>";   
}

}
//Closing Connection with Server
mysql_close($connection);
?>                  
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Still not working. The query is not working . I have put an if before echo it is not true .